# Arithmetic Progression with many answers

Tags: arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

a/b , ab , a−b , a+b

Above shows real numbers that belong to an arithmetic progression in order. Find the next term of this sequence.

In the question I was able to come up with different answers like find d and using formula of of a + (n-1)*d
Then another answer is 2(a+b) = a-b + variable

But I guess there needs to be a term which is simple
Got any Ideas?

Comment: Third difference is $2b.$ What happens if this is equated to first and second differences, and try to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they belong to an AP, then suppose the first term of the AP is given by $A$ and the common difference is $d$. Thus, we have the following equations:

$$
a/b = A \\
ab = A + d \\
a - b = A + 2d \\
a + b = A + 3d \\
$$

Solving the above system yields: $ a = -9/8, b = -3/5, A = 15/8, d = -6/5$.

Thus, the next term would be $A + 4d = \boxed{-\frac{117}{40}}$